# config subplot axis with common configuration

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to config all subplots with the same axis configuration. below code works but in subplot increase, we need add more elif to handle new axis config. how to simplify this code to handle subplots with variable name as argument?

```
xaxis,yaxis = get_xyaxis()
for i,yname in enumerate(colnames):        
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x=df[xname],
        y=df[yname],           
        name=yname)      
    fig.add_trace(
        trace1,
        row=i+1,
        col=1
    )
    if i == 0:
        fig.update_layout(
            xaxis1=xaxis,
            yaxis1=yaxis,
        )
    elif i == 1:
        fig.update_layout(
            xaxis2=xaxis,
            yaxis2=yaxis,
        )
    elif i == 2:
        fig.update_layout(
            xaxis3=xaxis,
            yaxis3=yaxis,
        )
```

I try `"xaxis%d"%(i + 1)=xaxis` but it doesn't work!

full code:

import re
import pandas as pd

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

def plot_line(df,pngname):    
    fontsize = 10
    title = "demo"
    xlabel = "KeyPoint"
    ylabel = "Duration(secs)"
    xname = df.columns[0]
    colnames = df.columns[1:]
    
    n = len(colnames)
```

O

```
    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=n, cols=1,
        shared_xaxes=True,
        vertical_spacing = 0.02,
    )

    xaxis,yaxis = get_xyaxis()
    for i,yname in enumerate(colnames):        
        trace1 = go.Scatter(
            x=df[xname],
            y=df[yname],
            text=df[yname],
            textposition='top center',
            mode='lines+markers',            
            marker=dict(
                size=10,
                line=dict(width=0,color='DarkSlateGrey')),            
            name=yname)
        
        fig.add_trace(
            trace1,
            row=i+1,
            col=1
        )
        # TODO
        if i == 0:
            fig.update_layout(
                xaxis1=xaxis,
                yaxis1=yaxis,
            )
        elif i == 1:
            fig.update_layout(
                xaxis2=xaxis,
                yaxis2=yaxis,
            )
        elif i == 2:
            fig.update_layout(
                xaxis3=xaxis,
                yaxis3=yaxis,
            )
                            
    xpading=.05
    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=20,t=40,r=10,b=40),
        plot_bgcolor='#ffffff',#'rgb(12,163,135)',
        paper_bgcolor='#ffffff',        
        title=title,
        title_x=0.5,
        showlegend=True,
        legend=dict(x=.02,y=1.05),        
        barmode='group',
        bargap=0.05,
        bargroupgap=0.0,
        font=dict(
            family="Courier New, monospace",
            size=fontsize,
            color="black"
        ),
    )
    fig.show()
    return

def get_xyaxis():
    xaxis=dict(
        title_standoff=1,
        tickangle=-15,            
        showline=True,
        linecolor='black',
        color='black',
        linewidth=.5,
        ticks='outside',
        showgrid=True,
        gridcolor='grey',
        gridwidth=.5,
        griddash='solid',#'dot',            
    )
    yaxis=dict(
        title_standoff=1,
        showline=True,
        linecolor='black',
        color='black',
        linewidth=.5,            
        showgrid=True,
        gridcolor='grey',
        gridwidth=.5,
        griddash='solid',#'dot',
        zeroline=True,
        zerolinecolor='grey',
        zerolinewidth=.5,
        showticklabels=True,
    )        
    return [xaxis,yaxis]

def main():
    data = [
        ['AAA',1,2,3],
        ['BBB',3,2,3],
        ['CCC',2,1,2],
        ['DDD',4,2,3],
        ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','v1','v2','v3'])
    print(df)
    plot_line(df,"./demo.png")
    return
    
main()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi, do you mind to share a full [mcve]?

Comment: You have edited my answer and asked a new question, but you have asked another question with the same content, so please restore my answer. And your question has already been resolved with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since all codes have been posted to your question, I will delete my comment as it does not address your issue and answer it instead. Applying the axis settings to all subplots can be accomplished by using Axis Update.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

def plot_line(df,pngname):    
    fontsize = 10
    title = "demo"
    xlabel = "KeyPoint"
    ylabel = "Duration(secs)"
    xname = df.columns[0]
    colnames = df.columns[1:]
    
    n = len(colnames)
    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=n, cols=1,
        shared_xaxes=True,
        vertical_spacing = 0.02,
    )

    xaxis,yaxis = get_xyaxis()
    for i,yname in enumerate(colnames): 
        trace1 = go.Scatter(
            x=df[xname],
            y=df[yname],
            text=df[yname],
            textposition='top center',
            mode='lines+markers',            
            marker=dict(
                size=10,
                line=dict(width=0,color='DarkSlateGrey')),            
            name=yname)
        
        fig.add_trace(
            trace1,
            row=i+1,
            col=1
        )
        fig.update_xaxes(xaxis)
        fig.update_yaxes(yaxis)
        # TODO
        # if i == 0:
        #     fig.update_layout(
        #         xaxis1=xaxis,
        #         yaxis1=yaxis,
        #     )
        # elif i == 1:
        #     fig.update_layout(
        #         xaxis2=xaxis,
        #         yaxis2=yaxis,
        #     )
        # elif i == 2:
        #     fig.update_layout(
        #         xaxis3=xaxis,
        #         yaxis3=yaxis,
        #     )
                            
    xpading=.05
    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=20,t=40,r=10,b=40),
        plot_bgcolor='#ffffff',#'rgb(12,163,135)',
        paper_bgcolor='#ffffff',        
        title=title,
        title_x=0.5,
        showlegend=True,
        legend=dict(x=.02,y=1.05),        
        barmode='group',
        bargap=0.05,
        bargroupgap=0.0,
        font=dict(
            family="Courier New, monospace",
            size=fontsize,
            color="black"
        ),
    )
    fig.show()
    return

def get_xyaxis():
    xaxis=dict(
        title_standoff=1,
        tickangle=-15,            
        showline=True,
        linecolor='black',
        color='black',
        linewidth=.5,
        ticks='outside',
        showgrid=True,
        gridcolor='grey',
        gridwidth=.5,
        griddash='solid',#'dot',            
    )
    yaxis=dict(
        title_standoff=1,
        showline=True,
        linecolor='black',
        color='black',
        linewidth=.5,            
        showgrid=True,
        gridcolor='grey',
        gridwidth=.5,
        griddash='solid',#'dot',
        zeroline=True,
        zerolinecolor='grey',
        zerolinewidth=.5,
        showticklabels=True,
    ) 
    return [xaxis,yaxis]

def main():
    data = [
        ['AAA',1,2,3],
        ['BBB',3,2,3],
        ['CCC',2,1,2],
        ['DDD',4,2,3],
        ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','v1','v2','v3'])
    print(df)
    plot_line(df,"./demo.png")
    return
    
main()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer, it's smart way! if I want to add annotation to each subplot, is it the same ?

Comment: Depending on what kind of annotation you want, you need to use add_annotation() and go.Scatter(mode='text').

Comment: Add update to question with annotation, only the last one works, and I would like to remove the "x%d"%(i+1) line as well.

Comment: The annotation only works at the end because there is a condition that the dy value must be greater than or equal to 2. And I am not sure how you want to annotate, but `fig.add_annotation(... row=n,col=n)` can be used so you can specify the target subplot to annotate.